# border of button when I didnt set anything

Tags: android, button, border

I am beginner with android developing, so maybe this question is lame. When I create button, it have some border which is visible, even though I didn´t set any and background is just color. more here in sample:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonBlue"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/colorButtonBlue"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/big_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/loginButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how it looks(i hope its visible, on mobile its even more than on emulator) 
[image]

I know that I can create own style and supress this but still, I would like to understand why it is happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: add button background android:background="@null"

Comment: wau, nice hack and it works, thanks a lot! But I am still little bit confused why the border appears in my solution :-/

Comment: It is because of button behaviour. if you got solution please accept answer or upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border appears because of the default background of the button

Set button background too `null` will fix this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonBlue"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/big_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/loginButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this property for button

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I am not sure nor I am able to check in right now, but I think you should play with the android:elevation. You should probably change the elevation to 0, since I suppose the default is not. Hope it helps !